# NSString to NSNumber with some decimal separator

Tags: objective-c, ios, decimal, nsnumber, nsnumberformatter

The app I'm building now has a possibility to "download" text files and get the numbers from there. In the simulator everything works perfectly, but when I tested it on a device it just crashed. After a while I figured out that the problem was with the decimal separators. In that file I used `.` and the local setting of my iPhone require `,`. Example of that string:

```
Product 1;100.00
Product 2;82.85
Product 3;95.12
//etc...
```

After changing the the first few `.` into `,` I could successfully run the app till it reached the first `.`, so that's the problem.

I can easily replace all `.` into `,` programmatically, **BUT** I want this app to work in any country with any number format and not limit it to some specific market.

The code I was using to get these numbers:

```
NSString *fileContents = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:theKey];
NSArray *allLinedStrings = [fileContents componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]];
NSMutableArray *allStringNormalized = [NSMutableArray array];
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
for (int i = 0; i < allLinedStrings.count; i++) {
    NSString *bla = [allLinedStrings objectAtIndex:i];
    NSArray *bla1 = [bla componentsSeparatedByString:@";"];
    [allStringNormalized addObject:[formatter numberFromString:[bla1 objectAtIndex:1]]];
}
self.values = [NSArray arrayWithArray:allStringNormalized];
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand the problem correctly, you want `NSNumberFormatter` to always use `.` as the decimal separator, regardless of the phone's locale. The solution to this is simple: use the instance methods `setDecimalSeparator:` and `setCurrencyDecimalSeparator:` of `NSNumberFormatter` to set the decimal separator to `.`.

Note that you don't need to set both decimal separators. You use `setDecimalSeparator:` if your `numberStyle` is `NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle` and `setCurrencyDecimalSeparator:` if your `numberStyle` is `NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle`.

See [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for more details.

Comment: thanks, that's pretty much what I was looking for. Though I was hoping to find a way to use different separators(in case one string is using `.` and the others are using `,`)

Comment: You could run auto detection on the file. If you *know* it is either going to be . or , then just see which is present and use that one.